# Как сделать поле из квадратов с помощью QGraphicsScene C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

Не очень понимаю как пользоваться QGraphicsScene, чтобы создать ну хотя бы 5 на 5 поле из квадратов

Comment: Сделайте QGraphicsView например в дизайнере, в нём установите сцену QGraphicsView::setScene, к сцене добавьте квадратов функцией QGraphicsScene::addRect